# How to modify default user model acl when creating a relation with other persisted model in loopback?

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have created a user model extended from base User model and added a relationship to other persisted model. When i tried to access that relationmethods via explorer it s giving authorization error

My usermodel structure(json)

```
{
  "name": "teamuser",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "empid": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "designation": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
 "relations": {
    "tasks": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "task",
      "foreignKey": "userid"
    }
  },
 "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

MyTask Model structure(json)

```
{
  "name": "task",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "desc": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "startdate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "enddate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
"relations": {
    "teamuser": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "teamuser",
      "foreignKey": "userid"
    },
    "project": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "project",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
 "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

When i try to hit this below method in explored i am getting the error

http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/teamusers/5/tasks?access_token=AQVBwaoo1g0msk2eRvyAqbybCvKmswhHfLh1SeNYrzmsvn1gmCou5EaDBTpaiA2M

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:376:21\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/lib/model.js:313:7\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/common/models/acl.js:465:23\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:251:17\n    at done (/Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:132:19)\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:572:34\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/common/models/acl.js:447:17\n    at /Users/mohamediqbalsaleem/Documents/easasoft/Testcb/node_modules/loopback/common/models/role.js:268:21"


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the default ACL behavior for relations in Loopback. From the docs:

> By default, all related model methods have a DENY ALL ACL set. You
>   need to explicitly grant access.  ACLs do not inherit from the target
>   model's endpoint. So, for example, even if the books model's default
>   ACL is ALLOW $authenticated for GET /books, the route GET
>   /user/{id}/books default will still be DENY ALL.

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Accessing+related+models

You will need to explicitly set the ACL for /teamusers/{id}/tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In "teamuser" model your base model is "User". It's inheriting it's feature. 
You can override it by simple way -

Just override parents "ACL" by yours "ACL" -

```js
{
  "name": "teamuser",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "empid": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "designation": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
 "relations": {
    "tasks": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "task",
      "foreignKey": "userid"
    }
  },
 "acls": [
  {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "accessType": "READ",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
 ],
  "methods": {}
}
```